# Python Time function for MySQL DB

Tags: python, mysql, json, python-2.7, twitter

Using Python, I'm streaming tweets that I insert in a MySQL db.
There, the date column have a datetime type.
Using these libraries:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import MySQLdb
import time
import json
```

And this Class

```
      class listener(StreamListener):
        def on_data(self, data):
          all_data = json.loads(data)
          tweet = all_data["text"]
          ID_Tweet = all_data["id_str"]

          c.execute("INSERT INTO tweets (t_date, user_name, tweet, ID_Tweet) VALUES (%s,%s, %s,%s)",
            (time.localtime(), username, tweet, ID_Tweet))
....
```

I always got this warning:

> Warning (from warnings module):   File
>   "C:\Users\OB\Desktop\TwT\connect.py", line 35
>       (time.time(), username, tweet, ID_Tweet)) Warning: Data truncated for column 't_date' at row 1

and when I checked the db, the tweets are inserted but with this time value
 **0000-00-00 00:00:00**